# What is probability of this event?

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-distribution

I have 20 balls with numbers from 1 to 20. First I write on paper two different numbers from 1 to 20 and than pick randomly 10 balls (without return). What is probability that both of my numbers are on picked balls?

Comment: Note that the probability is different if you pick the balls with return or without. Also, if this is a homework question, it should be tagged with [self study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) tag.

Comment: It doesn't have to be homework to require the self-study tag.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest definitions of probability is the number of simple events which satisfy the event of interest divided by all possible simple events.  At least when all simple events are equally probable (otherwise you have to scale).

So for this situation, there are 20 choose 10 total simple events.  Furthermore, there are 18 choose 8 ways to have the two chosen ones.

$\frac{18\choose 8}{20\choose10}=\frac{9}{38}\approx0.2368$

Another way of thinking about it is reverse.  The probability of picking one of the 10 on the first try is 10/20 and on the second is 9/19.  Multiply these and get the same answer.